# Increment key if key already in dict

Tags: python

Im trying to auto increment a dict keys if a key already exists

I have achieve it using a while loop but I wonder if there would be a cleaner/faster way to do it

```
foo = {}
foo["a"] = "bar"
foo["a (1)"] = "baz"
key = "a"
count = 0
key_check = key
while key_check in foo:
    count += 1
    key_check = key + " ({})".format(count)

foo[key_check] = "bazzz"
print foo
>>>{'a': 'bar', 'a (1)': 'baz', 'a (2)': 'bazzz'}
```

Comment: That's going to be really slow as more and more keys get added and the loop has to go through more and more entries. It only really makes sense if such collisions are expected to be rare.

Comment: this will be applied only with dict of few entries (less than 10), but I am looking for a better solution anyway

Comment: What are your constraints? Does this have to be a dict? Why not a dict with list entries?

Comment: Why not a dict with integer keys? next_key = 1 + max(foo.keys()) or somesuch.

Comment: This seems like you need to restructure your design choice more than anything. What are you trying to achieve? If a is your only key, why not just use a list? If not, what not use nested dicts?

Comment: Consider using dict views and consider using a single key, such as `'a'` that has the value of a list with the elements.

Comment: @dawg and what if I want to retrive the value of only a specific key? {'a': ["'bar", "baz", "bazzz"]}, I would like to retrive bazz if the third key "a" is selected... that complexify the whole script. I want to have unique key in order to keep everything simple

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you are using this. What would del the key_check key? Another process? If you want random access of the third `'a'` that is easy with either a list or dict (with integer keys) as a value for the key. What happens with yours if `'a'` is no longer there? Are the keys `'a (X)'` deleted as well?  Again -- what is the use case?

Comment: @dawg and @Below the Radar are right, dict indexing to lists is probably the best compromise of simplicity and convenience. In response to "What if I what to retrieve the value of only a specific key?" --->   `dictionary['a'][2]` will give you this, you just have to index first the key and then the index in the list, way better than storing the index as a string. String processing is clunky by comparison to integer indexing

Comment: @DerekG and dawg I understand your point, but instead of just displaying a unique key into an interface, I will have to test if the selected key have duplicates and calculate its index before retrieving the correct value, that's my point

Comment: No you don't. Say I want to access index 7 of key "a". I execute `dict['a'][7]` in a try catch block and except IndexError. If there is no element 7, an IndexError is thrown and caught, and you know that there isn't a 7th element. Basically one operation.

Comment: This definitely seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way is to use a mapping between key and a list of values for it. Use defaultdict for this. If a key isn't present, it will call the defaultfactory function* and returns it.

- here a default factory function is the `list` function that returns an empty list

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# foo=[("a", "bar"), ("a", "bazz")] # some random input that maps keys to values, and keys repeat
d = defaultdict(list) # return empty list if key doesn't exist
for k, val in foo:
    d[k].append(val)
# If you don't want a simple dict instead of defaultdict
d = dict(d)
print(d)
>>>{'a': ['bar', 'bazzz']}
```

You can also do this without defaultdict with dict's setdefault method.

```py
# foo=[("a", "bar"), ("a", "bazz")]


d = {}
for k, val in foo:
    # set [] as the default value for k if k doesn't already exist, and return the value of k
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(val)

print(d)
>>>{'a': ['bar', 'bazzz']}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I think what commenters are trying to explain is that you never need to change the name of the key when trying to do an operation like this one. Instead, you can build your logic so that the value in each key/value pair updates. For example, in this snippet, I have a list of words, and I want to know how many of each word I have. The part of the code after 'except' is the part that fires when the key isn't found. This example doesn't match your use case exactly, but I think/hope it demonstrates the overall point effectively.

```
tokens = ['now', 'when', 'i', 'say', 'that', 'i', 'am', 'in', 'the', 'habit', 'of', 'going', 'to', 'sea', 'whenever', 'i', 'begin', 'to', 'grow', 'hazy', 'about', 'the', 'eyes', 'and', 'begin', 'to', 'be', 'over', 'conscious', 'of', 'my', 'lungs', 'i', 'do', 'not', 'mean', 'to', 'have', 'it', 'inferred', 'that', 'i', 'ever', 'go', 'to', 'sea', 'as', 'a', 'passenger', 'for', 'to', 'go', 'as', 'a', 'passenger', 'you', 'must', 'needs', 'have', 'a', 'purse', 'and', 'a', 'purse', 'is', 'but', 'a', 'rag', 'unless', 'you', 'have', 'something', 'in', 'it', 'besides', 'passengers', 'get', 'sea', 'sick', 'grow', 'quarrelsome', 'dont', 'sleep', 'of', 'nights', 'do', 'not', 'enjoy', 'themselves', 'much', 'as', 'a', 'general', 'thing;', 'no', 'i', 'never', 'go', 'as', 'a', 'passenger;', 'nor', 'though', 'i', 'am', 'something', 'of', 'a', 'salt', 'do', 'i', 'ever', 'go', 'to', 'sea', 'as', 'a', 'commodore', 'or', 'a', 'captain', 'or', 'a', 'cook', 'i', 'abandon', 'the', 'glory', 'and', 'distinction', 'of', 'such', 'offices', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'like', 'them', 'for', 'my', 'part', 'i', 'abominate', 'all', 'honorable', 'respectable', 'toils', 'trials', 'and', 'tribulations', 'of', 'every', 'kind', 'whatsoever', 'it', 'is', 'quite', 'as', 'much', 'as', 'i', 'can', 'do', 'to', 'take', 'care', 'of', 'myself', 'without', 'taking', 'care', 'of', 'ships', 'barques', 'brigs', 'schooners', 'and', 'what', 'not', 'and', 'as', 'for', 'going', 'as', 'cook', 'though', 'i', 'confess', 'there', 'is', 'considerable', 'glory', 'in', 'that', 'a', 'cook', 'being', 'a', 'sort', 'of', 'officer', 'on', 'ship', 'board', 'yet', 'somehow', 'i', 'never', 'fancied', 'broiling', 'fowls;', 'though', 'once', 'broiled', 'judiciously', 'buttered', 'and', 'judgmatically', 'salted', 'and', 'peppered', 'there', 'is', 'no', 'one', 'who', 'will', 'speak', 'more', 'respectfully', 'not', 'to', 'say', 'reverentially', 'of', 'a', 'broiled', 'fowl', 'than', 'i', 'will', 'it', 'is', 'out', 'of', 'the', 'idolatrous', 'dotings', 'of', 'the', 'old', 'egyptians', 'upon', 'broiled', 'ibis', 'and', 'roasted', 'river', 'horse', 'that', 'you', 'see', 'the', 'mummies', 'of', 'those', 'creatures', 'in', 'their', 'huge', 'bake', 'houses', 'the', 'pyramids', 'no', 'when', 'i', 'go', 'to', 'sea', 'i', 'go', 'as', 'a', 'simple', 'sailor', 'right', 'before', 'the', 'mast', 'plumb', 'down', 'into', 'the', 'forecastle', 'aloft', 'there', 'to', 'the', 'royal', 'mast', 'head', 'true', 'they', 'rather', 'order', 'me', 'about', 'some', 'and', 'make', 'me', 'jump', 'from', 'spar', 'to', 'spar', 'like', 'a', 'grasshopper', 'in', 'a', 'may', 'meadow', 'and', 'at', 'first', 'this', 'sort', 'of', 'thing', 'is', 'unpleasant', 'enough', 'it', 'touches', 'ones', 'sense', 'of', 'honor', 'particularly', 'if', 'you', 'come', 'of', 'an', 'old', 'established', 'family', 'in', 'the', 'land', 'the', 'van', 'rensselaers', 'or', 'randolphs', 'or', 'hardicanutes', 'and', 'more', 'than', 'all', 'if', 'just', 'previous', 'to', 'putting', 'your', 'hand', 'into', 'the', 'tar', 'pot', 'you', 'have', 'been', 'lording', 'it', 'as', 'a', 'country', 'schoolmaster', 'making', 'the', 'tallest', 'boys', 'stand', 'in', 'awe', 'of', 'you', 'the', 'transition', 'is', 'a', 'keen', 'one', 'i', 'assure', 'you', 'from', 'a', 'schoolmaster', 'to', 'a', 'sailor', 'and', 'requires', 'a', 'strong', 'decoction', 'of', 'seneca', 'and', 'the', 'stoics', 'to', 'enable', 'you', 'to', 'grin', 'and', 'bear', 'it', 'but', 'even', 'this', 'wears', 'off', 'in', 'time']

result ={}
for i in tokens:
    try:
        result[i] +=1
    except:
        result[i] = 1

# result is {'now': 1,
# 'when': 2,
# 'i': 17,
# 'say': 2,
# 'that': 4,
# 'am': 2,
# 'in': 8,
# 'the': 16, ... }
```